# how to replace dot with comma in a column in dask cudf?

Tags: dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe, cudf

I would like to replace a string column's "." with "," in a dask_cudf dataframe.

example

```
 tdf = cudf.DataFrame("A":["x.y", "a.b"])
 temp = dask_cudf.from_cudf(tdf, npartitions=1)
 temp["A"] = temp["A"].str.split(".", expand=False)
 temp.head(2)
```

I got:

```
  A
0 [x, y]
1 [a, b]
```

I need:

```
 A
0  x,y
1  a,b
```

I have tried :

```
  temp  = temp["A"].str.split(".", expand=False).join(sep=",")
  temp.head(2)
```

I got error:

```
  "Series" object has no attribute "join".
```

How can I do this kind of replacement ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

don't use `split`, use `str.replace`

`tdf['A'] = tdf['A'].str.replace('.',',')`

outputs:

```
    A
0   x,y
1   a,b
```